# How display sql function in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a SQL function that counts quantity of repeated elements in SQL table:

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(student_id)
FROM students
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(student_id) <= 10
```

This function should display all groups where quantity of students less or equals 10 (I believe), and I'm trying to display this groups using this code:

```
public List<String> findGroups() throws IOException, SQLException {
    String createTables = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("src/main/resources/database/findGroup.sql")));
    Statement statement = connectToEdit().createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(createTables);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while(resultSet.next()){
        result.add(resultSet.getString("group_id"));
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, it displays nothing. How can I display groups with quantity of students?

Comment: But you aren't printing out anything?

Comment: @Mureinik im printing list but this list contains nothing

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your query, you don't select a non-aggregated column (`group_id`)  with an aggregated one `student_id`

Try same query with `GROUP BY group_id,student_id`